# Need help main menu C++

Tags: c++

So I have a program that is kind of like a quiz. The main menu is supposed to see whether they want to play then if they want to play what type of quiz. However it just keeps looping or it just ends the program. I think it might have to do with the if statements.

```
void main_menu()
{
cout << "--------------------(1)Start Quiz------------------\n";
cout << "-----------------------(2)Quit---------------------\n";
cin >> c;
if (c == 1)
{
    cout << "--------------------(1)Riddles------------------------\n";
    cout << "--------------------(2)Math IQ------------------------\n";
    cout << "----------------------(3)Quit-------------------------\n";
    cin >> o;
    if(o == 1)
    {
        while (o == 1)
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            main_menu();
            system("CLS");
            random = rand() % 11 + 1;
            switch (random)
            {
            case 1:
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI14();
                break;
            case 2:
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI3();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI11();
                break;
            case 3:
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI3();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI8();
                break;
            case 4:
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI3();
                void QuestionI5();
                break;
            case 5:
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI3();
                void QuestionI6();
                break;
            case 6:
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI2();
                break;
            case 7:
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI14();
                void QuestionI15();
                break;
            case 8:
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI14();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI3();
                break;
            case 9:
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI14();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI13();
                break;
            case 10:
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI13();
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "Your score is: " << s * 10 << "%.\n";
    if(o == 2)
        while (o == 2)
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
            main_menu();
            system("CLS");
            random = rand() % 11 + 1;
            switch (random)
            {
            case 1:
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI14();
                break;
            case 2:
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI3();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI11();
                break;
            case 3:
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI3();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI8();
                break;
            case 4:
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI3();
                void QuestionI5();
                break;
            case 5:
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI3();
                void QuestionI6();
                break;
            case 6:
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI2();
                break;
            case 7:
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI14();
                void QuestionI15();
                break;
            case 8:
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI14();
                void QuestionI13();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI3();
                break;
            case 9:
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI4();
                void QuestionI15();
                void QuestionI14();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI1();
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI13();
                break;
            case 10:
                void QuestionI7();
                void QuestionI5();
                void QuestionI10();
                void QuestionI9();
                void QuestionI2();
                void QuestionI8();
                void QuestionI11();
                void QuestionI6();
                void QuestionI12();
                void QuestionI13();
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "Your score is: " << s * 10 << "%.\n";
        }
        }
    }
    if (o == 3)
    {
        ifstream input("High_Score.txt");
        input >> high_score;
        ofstream output("High_Score.txt");
        if (s * 10 > high_score)
        {
            cout << "You have a high score!!!!!\n";
            output << s * 10;
        }
        else
        {
            output << high_score;
        }
        cout << "See you next time!\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
if (c == 2)
{
    ifstream input("High_Score.txt");
    input >> high_score;
    ofstream output("High_Score.txt");
    if (s * 10 > high_score)
    {
        cout << "You have a high score!!!!!\n";
        output << s * 10;
    }
    else
    {
        output << high_score;
    }
    cout << "See you next time!\n";
    system("pause");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
}
```

Any help would be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably unrelated: `void QuestionI7();` and its oft-repeated ilk are function declarations, not calls. They don't do anything.

Comment: It looks like all of your variables are global. This is a bad idea. It becomes an extremely bad idea as you write larger and larger programs because it is extremely hard to track who is doing what to whom. A variable should be declared in the tightest scope possible and as close to where it is used as possible.

Comment: You have provided 300 lines of uncompilable code. You will help yourself and others if you isolate one problem by making a [mre] and focus on that one problem. If making the MRE doesn't reveal to you the error of your ways and how to fix it, edit the question and add the MRE.

Comment: `void QuestionI7();`, and all the others, don't do what you think they do. They do absolutely nothing. Did you actually write such a huge pile of code without even testing a sigle line of it? Writing a metric ton of code all at once, and only then seeing it if it works is a recipe for failure. Professional C++ developers don't write code like this. We write a few lines of code, maybe a dozen lines, or a little bit more, compile, test them, see if they work, then write the next handful lines of code. This way problems are identified, analyzed, and fixed, very quickly.

Comment: @user4581301 When I just call the functions without typing void in front of them I get tons of errors saying it needs an identifier

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tested tons of code and it all worked until I tried to add another option for the type of questions

Comment: That cannot be true, Nothing in these `switch` statements could possibly be calling any other function. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I didn't have void in front of all these until I added the new option and I got hundreds of errors saying that it required identifiers.

Comment: Then why are you posting code that won't even compile, but instead describe a completely different problem, in your question? The shown code does not "just keeps looping". It won't even compile. You cannot expect a helpful answer if the shown code is not consistent with the question being asked.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The code compiles but it doesn't work like it is supposed to

Comment: In that case I go back to my original comment: the reason "it doesn't work like it is supposed to" is because `void something();` in the switch statement doesn't do anything. If you get a compilation error, and do not understand the reason for it, adding random keywords to code is unlikely to fix anything. You need to understand the reason for the "hundreds of errors saying that it required identifiers". "`void`" is not even an identifier. It's a keyword. Please read [ask] in stackoverflow.com's [help].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The void something part works but the part that doesn't work is the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will keep looping because of the while loops' conditions. It check if o is a specified number, but it won't change inside the while loop so it will loop forever. You options to fix it are:
1. Use 'break' statement to stop the while loop and get out of it. Notice that it isn't always safe to use it, at least at the old versions of c++ and c. You'll find that people prefer to not use it inside loops.
2. Use a bool value or a number that is set to be true at the beginning and may be changed inside the loop.